# How to Use --noreload in Django app with gunicorn on remoter server ( ubuntu VM )

Tags: python-3.x, django, cloud, gunicorn

What is the equivalent of `Python3 manage.py runserver --noreload` on remote Virtual machine with gunicorn,django and nginx. The problem is that i'm calling a function to download data using Apscheduler and if i run `--norelaod` command on local the files are downloaded perfectly, but on cloud i'm using gunicorn and  the function is called twice or thrice hence a lot of extra files, so how do i use something like `--noreload` on gunicorn?

EDIT:- The MAIN problem is that i'm getting duplicate files , and the behavior is similar to running your app in local without `--noreload` . So any solution to the main problem will do it for me.

Comment: Normally you run your Django application with the wsgi.py file with gunicorn. There is no relaod then.

Comment: @Marco Then why am i getting duplicate files, as if it's running on reload.

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071262/how-to-stop-gunicorn-when-flask-application-exits/46333649) ?

Comment: @Arun T yes, but not getting much help from it