FastAPI Docker Container is not restarting when FastAPI is terminated
I have a fastapi app running inside a docker instance. When an error occurs inside my "task_func" I want the docker container to restart.
Hence I am explicitly terminating the FastAPI server when an error occurs inside the "task_func". Using:
 os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)

I have set restart: always in docker-compose.yaml file and docker container should restart. But docker container is not restarting automatically
Python Code:
app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event() -> None:
    """Starts processing"""
    logging.info("VP: Starting Server")
    task = asyncio.create_task(task_func())
    try:
        await task
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error(f"Following exception has occured: {error}")
        logging.info("Exception has occured. Shutting down uvicron server")
        # Terminating FastAPI instance
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event() -> None:
    """Shuts down the app."""
    logging.info("Shutting down")

docker-compose.yml
events_consumer:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./events_consumer
      target: dev

Please help.

How are you running your application? os.getpid will probably reference a specific uvicorn/gunicorn worker, and will not terminate the master process - so the main process is still running. One possible solution is to make gunicorn write its pid to a pid file, then read the content of that pid file and send sigterm to gunicorn instead. Edit: it also seems gunicorn watches the return value from a worker, so sys.exit(4) / sys.exit(errno.EINTR) should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071262/how-to-stop-gunicorn-when-flask-application-exits

How about, for example, adding an endpoint for health and status check:
status_router = APIRouter(prefix="/status", tags=["Status"])

@status_router.get("/health")
def health() -> dict[str, str]:
    """
    Check if server is running
    ---
    **return:** {"status": "ok"}
    """
    return {"status": "ok"}


@status_router.get("/readiness")
async def readiness() -> dict[str, str]:
    """
    Check if server properly communicate with database
    ---
    **return:** {"status": "ok"}
    """

    if await DB.check_connection():
        return {"status": "ok"}
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=503, detail="Connection to database failed")

and setting up checking for these enpoints in the kubernetes manifest:
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /api/status/health
    port: 7777
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 5
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 6
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /api/status/readiness
    port: 7777
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 15
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 6

